# How to detect where a stretched canvas was clicked?

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouse, sandbox

I have a canvas that is stretched out since I am making a sandbox game. I can not use the normal method of detecting the pixel on the page a canvas is clicked because I need to know which stretch pixel was clicked. Hopefully this makes sense?

Comment: Some code would be nice

Comment: First, edit your question to include a runnable Snippet that sets up the basic environment needed to do what you want. Next, show us what you have tried so far and explain *why* it won't work for your situation. See [the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details on how to ask a better question and get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is scale the position based on your current canvas size and original canvas size.

```
function scaleCursorPoint(int mouseX, int mouseY, ctx) {
    return {
        x: mouseX * (ctx.canvas.width / ctx.width), 
        y: mouseY * (ctx.canvas.height / ctx.height) 
   };
}
```

`ctx` (which is gotten with `canvas.getContext('2d')` has the width of the original unstretched. `ctx.canvas` gets the original `canvas` DOM element. `ctx.canvas.width` is the size of the DOM element (the stretched size).

Divide the two and you get the scale value. Then just multiple that scale value with the points you got and you're good

Comment: @InvincibleBlaze If it's the answer, please click the check mark under the number so others who come across this question know the answer as well. Glad it works. =)